# Bold Partial Text String in Excel w/o Formula

Tags: excel, replace, formula

I using the CONCATENATE function to merge multiple columns with some text and carriage returns. The result is being pasted as values in the next column. The result will look like this:

Section 1-1

Y = -77.687

X = (-3.454,13.500)

I want the first line of the result to be bold. I dont want to use code as I'm not comfortable with it.

Can anyone please help find a way in which I can use a formula/ conditional formatting/ replace or other non-code options to make the text string bold AFTER PASTING IT AS VALUES.

PS: The operation needs to be carried out in approx 1000 cells and every time the first line will be "Section ..." ( the "1-1" part may/may not change)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear. If all of your lines are in a single cell, you can only format a single line manually, or by using VBA.  If your lines are in different cells, you can use conditional formatting as suggested by @lenwe

Comment: @RonRosenfeld all the lines are in a single cell so cant use conditional formatting and not yet using VBA. Any other way?

Comment: As I wrote, manually or VBA.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Conditional Formatting to solve this. Simply set new rules for the column to format only cells beginning with "Section". You can see how I did it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqNfA.png). Then format the font that it becomes bold.

Comment: The above will bold the entire string not just the word 'SECTION'

Answer (score 0):

If it's not concatenated, write the cell as normal with no formatting.  Then F2 to reenter the cell, highlight the word you want to bold (or otherwise format; underline, color, etc.)  apply ^B (Click Bold in ribbon) or whatever other formatting you need.